# Compute the integral $\int_{|z|=1}z^{-n}e^zdz,\quad n=1,2,\ldots.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find the integral

$$\int_{|z|=1}z^{-n}e^zdz,\quad n=1,2,\ldots.$$
where $z$ is a complex number. I'm sure there should be a theorem or formula something can easily solve it. Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Use the residue theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: Perhaps I'm not allowed to use any theorem beyond Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: I can't see clearly how Cauchy theorem can help you here. Now, Cauchy's Integral Formula solves it at once.

Comment: Though residue theorem and the integral formula are much more helpful, just thought I'd note that the integral is equivalent to: $i\int_{0}^{2π}e^{e^{it}+it(1-n)}dt,\quad n=1,2,\ldots.$

Answer (score 1):

With [CIF](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html) :

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z^n}dz=\left.\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left(e^z\right)\right|_{z=0}=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}$$

Comment: Thanks! But can you provide more information? I don't see clearly how the first equation could happen.

Comment: @Kelan Follow the link I give there.

Comment: But I don't see where $\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}$ came from and why $z=0$.

Comment: @Kelan Did you follow the link? It is the very last formula there, and in this case the winding number $\;\gamma\;$ is one.

Comment: Oh! I got it! But still I don't see why we want $z=0$ there.

Comment: Because that's the point $\;z_0\;$ in our case!: $\;z^n=(z-0)^n\;$ .

Comment: Oh! I finally see all of this. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Kelan My pleasure.